# Newly launched program windows not on top

Tags: debian, x11, gnome3

I am experiencing this issue with Debian 10 / X11 / GNOME 3.30.2.

I observe inconsistent behavior in the z-ordering of windows, when having a program window open and focused, and then launching another program or a further instance of the already-open program. Sometimes the window of the newly launched program opens on top and in focus, whereas other times the new window opens below the active program window and not in focus, while displaying a floating message that the launched program "is ready". It is entirely unclear to me when to expect one outcome rather than the other.

I would prefer the behavior to be consistent, instead of the system switching between the two modes without clear indication of when one or the other is to be expected.

How can I make windows of newly launched programs always appear on top and in focus?

Edit 1: Example

I have an in-focus instance of GNOME Terminal opened in a maximized window.

I launch another program by typing SUPER + entering program name + ENTER, by clicking on the program icon in the dash, or by clicking on the program icon in list of all installed programs.

If I launch another instance of GNOME Terminal, it consistently opens the new window below the active window, and GNOME displays a floating message that Terminal "is ready".

If I launch VLC media player, sometimes it opens below with a message that it "is ready", other times appears on top and in focus.

If I launch GNOME Files, it consistently opens on top and in focus.

Comment: Can you clarify "opening new windows when already viewing an open window with an active program". Is this a window of an app that is already open, or of a new app? Also can you add some pictures of what is happening.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thank you for the feedback. I edited parts of the description to clarify, and added an example of what I am experiencing. Please let me know if there is more I can do to improve the description.

Comment: Sorry but I just can't get my head around that first sentence of the second paragraph. What is it saying?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I did another try. Did the reversal of sentence structure increase comprehensibility?